# Where to insert the JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have made a layout using a GridBagLayout to force sub-components to stack from the bottom and up.

The only thing I have left is to make the "container" component scrollable.

I have tried inserting the JScrollPane in different locations, but I fail to find a working spot.

My 2 inner JPanels are aligned correctly at the bottom and they resize correctly when I resize the window. But when I resize the window too small for the text to fit, I want the "container" component to scroll.

Please help a newbie :)

**UPDATE 1: The scroll should be for the whole GridBagLayout. Not for each individual textpane's.**

**UPDATE 2: Changed the code to use BorderLayout instead, as it makes no difference to my scroll problem.**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class BorderTest extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new BorderTest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public BorderTest() {

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Grid Bag");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    container.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
    add(container);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
    bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    container.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
    textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
    bottom.add(textPane);

    JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
    textPane2.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
    textPane2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
    bottom.add(textPane2);

}

}
```

Screenshot when running the above code:

[image]

When I make the window smaller, the items does not fit (of course) and I then want vertical scrollbars to appear (but not horizontal as the words should just wrap instead)

[image]

As you can see, the "red" border are "outside" of the window, so putting a scrollpane here seems like a good idea. Here is the code with a scrollpane added:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class BorderTest extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new BorderTest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public BorderTest() {

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Grid Bag");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, 2));
    add(scrollPane);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    container.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(container);

    JPanel innerContainer = new JPanel();
    innerContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    innerContainer.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.PINK, 2));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(innerContainer);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
    bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    innerContainer.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
    textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
    bottom.add(textPane);

    JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
    textPane2.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
    textPane2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
    bottom.add(textPane2);

}

}
```

But the result is not what I want. Now horizontal scoll bars are added and making my text items one huge row wide:

[image]

Comment: That GridBagLayout is not doing much since you only have 1 component added with that layout (the grid is 1x1). I don't think you are understanding how it works. Why are you putting it on `gridx = 0;`, `gridy = 2;`?

Comment: The GridBagLayout is helping me to put the components bottom-to-top without having to set a fixe height on the inner components. I am just having issues with where to add the JScrollPane. I tried adding to to "container", but that did not work.

Comment: No, what is helping you put the components bottom to top is the BoxLayout of the `bottom` panel with the Y_AXIS. The GridBagLayout is achieving nothing. You could put those components in the south position in the BoirderLayout to achieve something similar.

Comment: Sorry, those were a typo. I have updated it. However, the Y_AXIS is not putting it at the bottom. It just stackes from top-to-bottom and without the GridBagLayout, it would cause the 2 panels to be 50% high each and fill the entire height.

Comment: Change the Y_AXIS to X_AXIS and you will see that the JPanels are still at the bottom. That is of the help from the GridBagLayout.

Comment: Yes I see now that you are using LAST_LINE_START to put them at the bottom still is a very weird use of GridBagLayout anyway (until you have more components at least). I'm going to write an answer about those `JScrollPane`s

Comment: I am using that way because I want the JPanels to be 100% wide. If I just put it SOUTH in a BorderLayout, it would not get 100% width while having the height dynamic. But then again, I am new to Java :)

Comment: Haha, you were right :) I could just use a BorderLayout instead. I feel stupid :)

Comment: But still did not help with the scollpane issue though :( I have tried  putting it before "container" and even "bottom", but still no luck. It just makes a super-wide scroll and prevents the JTextPane's to word-wrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a `JScrollPane` to a component, you simply have to create a `JScrollPane` with that component and then add the `JScrollPane` to the panel where you want the component.

So instead of:

```
panel.add(component, constraints);
```

use

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(component);
panel.add(scrollPane, constraints);
```

Of course you can use the `scrollPane` variable to customize the `JScrollPane` a little bit, check the documentation for it, but by simpling putting this in your code we have:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GridBag extends JFrame
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBag().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public GridBag()
    {

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Grid Bag");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        container.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        add(container);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        bottom.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
        container.add(bottom, c);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
        textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        bottom.add(new JScrollPane(textPane));

        JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
        textPane2.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
        textPane2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
        bottom.add(new JScrollPane(textPane2));
    }
}
```

And makes it look like this:

[image]

Which works but doesn't look very nice, so let me show you an example of how to make the proper height distribution using the `GridBagConstraints.weighty` properties.

What I'm going to do is add two panels to the `GridBagLayout` (2 cells) one over the other and use the `weighty` numbers to tell them how much space to take. For this I'll want to change the `c.fill` to `BOTH`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GridBag extends JFrame
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBag().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public GridBag()
    {

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Grid Bag");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        container.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        add(container);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; //make it fill both directions
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0; //modify this number to change the proportion of the screen division
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; //for this example anything here goes.

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JTextField("Put other components here"));
        //topPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 2));
        container.add(topPanel, c);

        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weighty = 1.0; //modify this number to change the proportion of the screen division

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        bottom.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
        container.add(bottom, c);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
        textPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        bottom.add(new JScrollPane(textPane));

        JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
        textPane2.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et ");
        textPane2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
        bottom.add(new JScrollPane(textPane2));
    }
}
```

And looks like this:

[image]

This takes half of the screen for the top components and half for the two textPanes, this is because the `weighty` of both cells (`topPanel` and `bottom`) is 1.0, the same value, so the proportion is 1:1. You can change those numbers to change how much space do they take. For example putting the first weighty to 0.5 will make it a proportion 1:2.

Comment: Note that I changed the comment at the end about the weighty values since they should go only from 0.0 to 1.0. Remember that the values themselves do not matter but the propoertion between them. The two having 1.0, or the two having 0.5 behaves exactly the same, as long as they are values greater than 0.0

Comment: Sorry, but I did not make myself clear. I don't want a scrollpane for each component. The scrollpane should be for the "container" (the red border area). I will only fill the "bottom" with more "items". No other components will be put inside the "container"

Comment: @DanieleTesta There is no essential difference, the `container` is a Component, I told you how to put JScrollPanes in components. So I'm sure you can figure out how to put it there instead of in the JTextPanes

Comment: But if I put the scrollpane before (or inside) the container, the textpanes do not wordwrap any more. Instead, they turn into one huge wide scrollable line. I will add screenshots to show you.

Comment: @DanieleTesla The ugly way to fix it is to set a max/preferred size manually. The right way to do it is use a layout that doesn't take as much space as it can. You don't want to use fill = HORIZONTAL/BOTH. I don't know off the top of my mind all the layouts that behave like this, but a quick google search gave a couple of candidates. Also I don't know why are you making all this layout structure if you are not going to put more components.

Comment: But I can't set the height manually as it changes when the window gets resized. Then I would have to add listeners to do this for me, which is a bit of ugly hack I think. That layout is a common chat layout that most chat clients that I have seen uses. It fills the chat from the bottom and up. Of course I will add more "items" as the chat progresses, but the layout needs to handle short chats as well of course.

Comment: I solved it using resize listeners on "bottom" and dynamically changing the height on "container" in there. Thanks for your help!